# Create TextBlock at run time

Tags: vb.net, wpf-controls, runtime, textblock

I'm trying to create checkboxes with word wrap at runtime. The XAML for a checkbox with word wrap looks like this:

```
<CheckBox Width="140" Height="35">
    <ContentControl>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">This is a long text with word wrap</TextBlock>
    </ContentControl>
</CheckBox>
```

Now I want to create this XAML with code but I do not know how to get it work. I'm able to create the checkbox and add it to the existing WrapPanel but the textBlock control does not have a content property. How can I add the content to the textBlock and how can I add both (contentControl and textBlock) to the checkbox?

```
For intIndex = 0 To m_aryActions.Length - 1

    Dim textBlock As TextBlock = New TextBlock
    Dim contentControl As ContentControl = New ContentControl
    Dim checkBox As CheckBox = New CheckBox

    textBlock.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap
    contentControl.Content = textBlock

    With checkBox
        .Width = 140
        .Height = 25
        .Name = "CheckBox" & intIndex
    End With

    WrapPanel.Children.Add(checkBox)

Next
```

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: Nobody an idea? Too easy or too often asked? I have searched but did not found a solution. Too difficult? I don't believe that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, find it by myself:

```
Dim textBlock As TextBlock = New TextBlock
Dim contentControl As ContentControl = New ContentControl
Dim checkBox As CheckBox = New CheckBox

With textBlock
    .TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap
    .Text = m_aryWishes(intIndex)
End With

contentControl.Content = textBlock

With checkBox
    .Width = intWidth
    .Height = intHeight
    .Content = contentControl
    .Name = "CheckBox" & intIndex
    .Padding = New System.Windows.Thickness(10, 0, 20, 0)
    .Focusable = False
    .ClickMode = ClickMode.Press
End With

WrapPanel.Children.Add(checkBox)
```